# c++ base class called but returning derived class

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++98

Before all, I am tied to C++98, how I wish our supplier (and their supplier) would update

I am working with a 3rd party framework from which I do have sources. I do not want to change the sources to make sure I am upwards and downwards compatible.

That framework has a base class `Channel` and derived classes `Digital` and `Analog`

```
class Channel
{
    getChannel(std::string chName)
    {
        //returns a Channel  
    }
    bool IsDigital()
    {
       //returns true for digital otherwise false
    }
}

class Digital : public Channel
{
    // functionality for Digital
}

class Analog : public Channel
{
    // functionality for Analog
}
```

The base class allows me to find a 'Channel' by calling the `getChannel(std::string chName)` method. the base class also has a method `IsDigital()`. That method returns true when the channel is Digital otherwise it is Analog.

Is there a way (or pattern) that I can use to request the channel from the base class and get returned a `Digital` or `Analog` (derived class) ? If I need to build classes in between to get it done it is ok for me.  I would like to prevent from loads of getting channels in the program and casting them and ending up with multiple variables.

```
Digital* d;
Analog*  a;
Channel* c;

c = framework->getChannel("name");
if (c->IsDigital())
{
   d = dynamic_cast<Digital>(c);       
}
else
{
   a = dynamic_cast<Analog>(c);       
}
```

I hope there is something possible like this. In my main code I use my IO class and helper class, where the helper class works with the framework to determine if it is a Digital or Analog channel, and the IO class can be either Digital or Analog.

```
MyInBetweenClass* helper;
MyOwnClass *ioD;
MyOwnClass *ioA;

ioD = helper(framework->getChannel("digitalname"));
ioA = helper(framework->getChannel("analogname"));

// here do something with ioD acting on the digital IO
//   or do something with ioA acting on the analog IO
```

Comment: You seem to be asking about the factory pattern - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Comment: Your example about your desired goal is very unclear. Also, what is framework? (I can guess it's a Channel base object).

Comment: Are you sure you must cast the result of getChannel? It seems awkward.

Comment: @NeilButterworth AFAIK I get a Channel object from the factory pattern, while I would like to have a Digital or Analog object.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe the framework is a custom c++ framework providing functionality for their hardware. I tried to explain a little better what I would like to achieve.

Comment: @ZDF Digital and Analog derive from Channel but have different functionalities. If I get an Cannel object, I cannot use the extra functionalities from Digital or Analog

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish that using a function template.

```
namespace MyApp
{
    template <typename T>
    T* getChannel(Framework* framework, std::string const& cname)
    {
       return dynamic_cast<T*>(framework->getChannel(cname));
    }
}
```

and use

```
Analog*  a = MyApp::getChannel<Analog>(framework, "name");
```

Comment: Would it be possible to have another class e.g. `MyIO` which can behave line Analog -or- Digital, so that 

`MyIO*  a = MyApp::getChannel<Analog>(framework, "name1");
MyIO*  d = MyApp::getChannel<Digital>(framework, "name2");`

Comment: @barts, sure it's possible. What's the relationship between `MyIO` and the other classes?

Comment: `MyIO` is a class that I still have to create, so I can relate it in any required way to the Channel, Digital and/or Analog class, however I cannot change the Channel, Digital and Analog classes.